# Extracting a range of columns using column ID

Tags: r

I am trying to extract a range of columns from a table file using the column names to specify the range.  I tried

```
dayTable[c("Peter":"Michael")]
```

and got

```
Error in "Peter":"Michael" : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.frame`(dayTable, c("Peter":"Michael")) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In `[.data.frame`(dayTable, c("Peter":"Michael")) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: A comma only gives the two columns named.  Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help you:

```
dayTable[do.call(seq, as.list(match(c("name1", "nameN"), names(dayTable))))]
```

Comment: I got the error message "Error in seq.default(NA_integer_, 6L) : 'from' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite"

Comment: @OtagoHarbour This mean that `"name1"` is not present in `dayTable`.

Comment: You are right.  I misspelled one of the names.  It works perfectly now.  Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
dayTable[, paste0("name",seq_len(N))]
```

A complete example:

```
set.seed(1)
dayTable <- 
data.frame(matrix(round(rnorm(5*5),2),ncol=5))
dayTable <- 
setNames(dayTable,paste0('name',seq_len(ncol(dayTable))))
N<-4
dayTable[, paste0("name",seq_len(N))]

# name1 name2 name3 name4
# 1 -0.63 -0.82  1.51 -0.04
# 2  0.18  0.49  0.39 -0.02
# 3 -0.84  0.74 -0.62  0.94
# 4  1.60  0.58 -2.21  0.82
# 5  0.33 -0.31  1.12  0.59
```

#### Edit after op clarification:

```
nn <- names(dayTable)[order(names(dayTable))]

dayTable[, nn[nn>"name2" & nn<"name5"]] 
## in your case change by Peter and karen

# name3 name4
# 1  1.51 -0.04
# 2  0.39 -0.02
# 3 -0.62  0.94
# 4 -2.21  0.82
# 5  1.12  0.59
```

Comment: I think I used a bad example.  Sorry.  The generic "name1" and "nameN" could be something like "Peter" and "Karen".  So every column starting with the column named "Peter" and ending  with the column named "Karen". Thanks,

Comment: Tha's why You should give a reproducible example. Try to use mine to clarify your idea!

Comment: Sorry but I don't get your point. what do you mean by **"column named "Peter" and ending with the column named "Karen"**?

Comment: There could be a number of columns named (in order): David, Peter, Michael, Brian, Karen, Linda.  I only want to choose the columns Peter, Michael, Brian, Karen

Comment: It seems that the new approach orders the names alphabetically rather than their order in the header.  So dayTable[, nn[nn>"Peter" & nn<"Karen"]] returns 0 columns but dayTable[, nn[nn<"Peter" & nn>"Karen"]] returns columns Linda and Michael.  Thanks,